# OOM error - unable to acquire 261244 bytes of memory, got 0

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to run spark job which is both data and processing intensive job on dataproc and getting OOM with below error

```
‘OOM error - unable to acquire 261244 bytes of memory, got 0’
```

To give overview - On collect action, job is shuffling TBs of data. Roughly ~6TB

What I know is mentioned error comes when executor runs out of memory but when I am increasing executor memory then executor per node is decreasing resulting in less vcores causing job to run slow.

Can anyone please help me with above error. I have tried everything which is being suggested on stackoverflow.

Dataproc configuration

[image: DataProc Config]

I am using highmem-16 dataproc machine.

Code cant be shared as it is massive code with lot of transformations and this is first action on data.

Comment: It would be good, if you can share the current dataproc configuration and also a code sample with the input and output data. In general depending on the collect action significant amount of data can sit in the driver memory thereby causing OOM.

Comment: Without looking at what you are trying to do, it is very difficult to identify the root cause. In general to avoid OOM there are couple of options a) increase memory b) look at application code to reduce shuffle. I would suggest that you run smaller samples of application code to see where the issue is happening

Comment: i have increased executor memory as well as driver memory . Lets see if it helps. If this doesnt work. I wod break up job in parts and will try to figure out the root cause. Thanks much!

Comment: Sure, the other thing to keep in mind is 6 TB is a lot of data to be shuffling around. Unless there is a very good reason look at reducing the size of the input data by applying filters upfront.

Comment: Sure let me try this too if possible.

Comment: You said you're trying to run a "collect action" on your 6TB data ? In addition, setting more than 30gb memory for a JVM is not wise.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestion..Actually OOM was thrown as there was heavy join in the code. I have identified that and broken down the join, which has solved my problem. @jjayadeep

Comment: @bash955 - yes I just wanted to check the sql thats why increased executor memory. Now has corrected that.